# gatsby contentful rich text raw is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, gatsby, contentful, gatsby-source-contentful

In Gatsby trying to make a simple website.
In my particular example I have a node with a rich text field from Contentful.
It simply says one plain text sentence.

```
{renderRichText(event.description.raw)}
```

However the call above returns:

[image]

My event.description looks like this in the console:

`description: raw: "{"data":{},"content":[{"data":{},"content":[{"data":{},"marks":[],"value":"Hard beats. Fast music. Sweaty bodies. ","nodeType":"text"}],"nodeType":"paragraph"}],"nodeType":"document"}"`

I can see this is a string and I've tried to play with JSON.parse and JSON.stringify before sending it in. But I can't tell what's the issue. It's a string and it can't read it as a JSON object.** I validated it as proper JSON too.**

event.js

```
const Event = ({ pageContext }) => {

    const { event } = pageContext
    console.log('grabbing event', event)
    const image = event.flyer
  
    return (
      <>
        <h2 className={styles.EventTitle}>{event.title}</h2>
        <div className={`row`}>
            <div className={` ${styles.EventInfo}`}> 
             {renderRichText(event.description.raw)}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className={`row`}>
            <img className={styles.EventImage} src={image}/>
            <div className={` ${styles.EventActions}`}>
              <Link to={event.ticket}><button className={styles.EventButton}>Tickets</button></Link> 
            </div>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  };

  export default Event;
```

gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require("path")

exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

    const queryContentfulResults = await graphql(`
    query Events {
      allContentfulEvent {
        nodes {
          contentful_id
          title
          starttime
          id
          ad_mats {
            file {
              url
            }
          }
          square_flyer {
            file {
              url
            }
          }
          ticketlink
          slug
          venue {
            name
            street_address
            city
          }
          description {
            raw
          }
        }
      }
    }
    `)

    const eventTemplate = path.resolve(`src/templates/event.js`);

    contentfulEvents = queryContentfulResults.data.allContentfulEvent.nodes.map( data => transformEvent(data));

    contentfulEvents.forEach(node => {
      console.log(node);
      createPage({
        path: `/events/${node.slug}`,
        component: eventTemplate,
        context: {
          event: node
        }
      });
    });


};

  const transformEvent = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return {
      title: data.title,
      description: data.description,
      slug: data.slug,
      ad_mats: data.ad_mats,
      flyer: data.square_flyer.file.url,
      ticket: data.ticketlink,
      date: data.starttime,
      venue: data.venue.name,
      address: data.venue.street_address,
      city: data.venue.city
    }
};
```

Mess around with as a string and as JSON before setting it to the function renderRichText,
added an empty options object, and validated the JSON. No changes from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the documentation of the package, it seems like you're passing the wrong object to the `renderRichText()` method. You don't need to pass `event.description.raw`. You should only pass `event.description`.

You can find more information [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-contentful/#rendering) and [here](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/tutorials/general/rich-text-and-gatsby/).

Comment: Yup, but I had some issues with how I was transforming my data too. I just did a passthrough and did exactly that! Thank you!